# generating sequence without duplicity xpages

Tags: xpages, custom-controls, lotus-notes

I have an application on xpages that needs to have a handle number for the user, and I am having problems with duplicate numbers when I have two users trying to save simultaneously. I have tried using FTSearch and UpdateIndex, both are not viable because they caused slowness on xpage. I would like other options to be generating this sequence without duplicity and without impacting server performance.

Comment: You need to do the number handling at a central place (agent on server)... other than that you will always have duplicate numbers....

Comment: Agents and XPages always have been an odd mix. Use a managed bean instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to distinguish: single server or multiple servers (presuming you don’t use Notes clients).

Single server:
Create a managed bean that you deploy a “application managed bean”. On load that bean takes the first entry from a view that is sorted descending of your sequence. It keeps that one in memory. A synchronised function `getNextNumber()` that internally calls a singleton provides you with the value you need

Multiple servers:
a) they can’t “see” each other (remote replication): change your sequence to include a server prefix. Or: add sequence numbers after replication only.

b) they see each other on https:
Design “application managed beans” that do the same a single server, except that they asks a “master” for the number. You then need to implement a mechanism that allows to dynamically change the master when the master is unresponsive. Some kind of negotiation protocol. (Common challenge in Cluster environments).

Comment: Singleton pattern is pretty troublesome, due to class loaders "go wild" in XPages. Just sayin'.

Comment: Not for application scope beans

Comment: I've never had a problem with class loaders where code is triggered within the NSF and not via pre-loading. If using Java and objects, lazy loading is a better approach than preloading - I used to have an initApp() method that loaded all applicationScope vars I might need, now I tend to load only the ones I need. Since this method should only be needed on save (unique numbers have to be set on commit to the NSF), I'm not aware of any scenarios blogged about where class loaders would cause problems, because it never needs pre-loading, just lazy-loading.

Comment: For the multiple server approach, one option would be defining the master server. For other servers, if master server is not available set a "TEMP_" + current server  + sequential, and use that. Then use an agent, or better the lazy loading code, to fixup any "TEMP_" codes with proper sequentials (and associated documents). Sequential number generation (single server or multiple) is not a Domino-specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more Domino related, nothing special with XPages. Read some advice from IBM [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21087993) and implement it as an agent. You can call it in PostSave event.

There are more things you have to bear with:

- in cluster or multiple replicas environment, only one server is allowed
  to grant sequential number, what makes it "single point of failure"
- what happens with gaps in number sequence? are they allowed?
- in XPages you have more options than agent, consider using servlet or RPC call

Comment: Agents have no place in XPages short of covering legacy code. They run concurrently anyway